# Select PivotItem programmatically with correct direction in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

to Vote

Hello WP Devs!

I have one issue with scrolling pivot items programmatically.

Imaging that you have two items "First" and "Second". Active is "First".

Then on special item tap I try to scroll to the next pivot item (set SelectedIndex from 0 to 1).

Scroll direction for some reason animated from to Right to Left (not from Left to Right as I expect).

p.s. all works just fine if I have more than two items. Seems to be a bug if Pivot Item Change Animation.

Does anyone known how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be a bug. Just create a new project under the name, **Windows Phone Pivot Application**

In this template, you will see two pivot items and it works perfectly fine. Maybe you are setting the wrong `SelectedIndex` when going from the second item to the first item.

Please provide some code sample so that we can analyze the situation.